# Modify a string's first letters based on certain types

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase based on certain conditions like below -

- `booking_engine` → `Booking Engine`
- `booking-engine` → `Booking Engine`
- `bookingEngine`  → `Booking Engine`
- `crsProvider`    → `CRS Provider`
- `crs_Provider`   → `CRS Provider`
- `crs-Provider`   → `CRS Provider`

I have done this function below, but with this approach, the last three conditions are not satisfying

```
beautifyString(key: string): string {
    let separateWord: string[];

    if (key.includes('_')) {
        separateWord = key.split('_');
    } else if (key.includes('-')) {
        separateWord = key.split('-');
    } else {
        separateWord = key.split(/(?=[A-Z])/g);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < separateWord.length; i++) {
        separateWord[i] =
            separateWord[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
            separateWord[i].substring(1);
    }

    return separateWord.join(' ');
}
```

Comment: How do you distinguish between `bookingEngine` and `crsProvider` cases? What is the criterion?

Comment: @ PM 77-1, Basically, these are a certain type of naming formats(will vary from user to user). But allowed types are, only six which I have mentioned above. I have added validation that the sting I will get must be in the above format.

But there are certain string which is creating problems like `crs_provider, crs-provider, crsProvider, pms_provider`. In these cases, I have to make crs and pms always to be in full uppercase.

Is there any extra parameter that will add to convert these specific cases otherwise it will split the based on _ - or camalCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments im not 100% positive what your criterion is but the function below *beautifies* a string and fulfills all your conditions by splitting it up either

- at `-` and [title-casing](https://titlecase.com/) it,
- at `_` and title-casing it,
- or by splitting up the [camelCase](https://techterms.com/definition/camelcase) and title-casing it.

You can to additional string manipulation later on (e. g. Capitalizing the first three letters as given in your result examples).

```js
const beautifyString = (word) => {
  let result = "";
  const splitters = ["-", "_"];

  if (word.includes(splitters[0])) result = word.split(splitters[0]);
  else if (word.includes(splitters[1])) result = word.split(splitters[1]);
  else result = word.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2").split(" ");

  return [...result.map((e, i) => e[0].toUpperCase() + e.slice(1))].join(" ");
};

console.log(beautifyString("booking_engine"));
console.log(beautifyString("booking-engine"));
console.log(beautifyString("bookingEngine"));
console.log(beautifyString("crsProvider"));
console.log(beautifyString("crs_Provider"));
console.log(beautifyString("crs-Provider"));
```

**TypeScript Version**

```
const beautifyString: (word: string) => string = (word: string) => {
  let result: string[] = [];
  const splitters = ["-", "_"] as const;

  if (word.includes(splitters[0])) result = word.split(splitters[0]);
  else if (word.includes(splitters[1])) result = word.split(splitters[1]);
  else result = word.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2").split(" ");

  return [
    ...result.map((e: string, i: number) => e[0].toUpperCase() + e.slice(1)),
  ].join(" ");
};

console.log(beautifyString("booking_engine")); // Booking Engine
console.log(beautifyString("booking-engine")); // Booking Engine
console.log(beautifyString("bookingEngine"));  // Booking Engine
console.log(beautifyString("crsProvider"));    // Crs Provider
console.log(beautifyString("crs_Provider"));   // Crs Provider
console.log(beautifyString("crs-Provider"));   // Crs Provider
```

---

**Edit**

If you want to capitalize the first three letters I suggest just defining a function which does the job dynamically. And then just nest the functions calls.

```js
const beautifyString = (word) => {
  let result = "";
  const splitters = ["-", "_"];

  if (word.includes(splitters[0])) result = word.split(splitters[0]);
  else if (word.includes(splitters[1])) result = word.split(splitters[1]);
  else result = word.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2").split(" ");

  return [...result.map((e, i) => e[0].toUpperCase() + e.slice(1))].join(" ");
};

const capitalizeFirstLetters = (word, amount) =>
  word.slice(0, amount).toUpperCase() + word.substr(amount, word.length);

console.log(capitalizeFirstLetters(beautifyString("crs_Provider"), 3));
```

**TypeScript Version**

```
const capitalizeFirstLetters: (word: string, amount: number) => string = (
  word: string,
  amount: number
) => word.slice(0, amount).toUpperCase() + word.substr(amount, word.length);

console.log(capitalizeFirstLetters(beautifyString("crs_Provider"), 3));  // CRS Provider
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is there any way to make the last three outputs like this `CRS Provider`. crs will be uppercase. Same as `pmsProvider, pms_Provider, pms-Provider` where I want PMS to be all in uppercase

Comment: Because pms_provider and crs_proiver these are some specif types which I want to beautify like this, for other cases it will beautify based on _ - and camelcase.